# Using string as index of a MultiDimensional Array in JAVA

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I am new to Java so I dont have much knowledge about it. I was working with Array when I found something really frustrating in Java.

I have a string array and I want the index to be a string. For example

```
String[][] a = new String[][]{};
a['person']['name'] = "something";
```

But Java doesnt let me do that. Please help me on this or some workaround for it.
Thanks

Comment: You can not do it with `array` or `arrayList`. Have a look at `HashTable` (or `HashMap`) class instead.

Comment: I think you can make use of `hashCode()` which returns a integer value, but indexing using that will be a mess. So better try `Map`

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use a `Map` with a user defined class as key:

```
Map<Category, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

`Category` can have properties such as an `enum` `type` such as `PERSON` and a `String` name field.

Make sure to override [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) methods to allow different `Category` objects to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `HashMap` for example with the name as key and "something" as value.

```
// Create a HashMap which stores Strings as the keys and values 
Map<String,String> example = new HashMap<String,String>();

// Adding some values to the HashMap
example.put( "Wayne", new String( "Rooney" ));
example.put( "Alan", new String( "Shearer" ));
example.put( "Rio", new String( "Ferdinand" ));
example.put( "John", new String( "Terry" )); 

// Find out how many key/value pairs the HashMap contains
System.out.println("The HashMap contains " + example.size() + " pairs");
```

Iterate over the map:

```
for (String key : example.keySet() ) {
    // Get the String value that goes with the key 
    String value = example.get( key );

    // Print the key and value
    System.out.println( key + " = " + value); 
 }
```

More info [here](http://binarynerd.com/java-tutorials/advanced-java/using-java-hashmaps.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try map of maps:

```
Map<String, Map<String, V>> map = //...
//...

map.get("person").get("name");
```

Comment: Hey is it possible to do something like this.
`map.put("name","xxx");
map.put("person",map1.put("name","xxx"));'
because sometimes i can put string and sometimes a map.

Comment: No, it is not possible(at first statement) if map is defined as Map of Map, then you put string as key and as a value.